# CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials throws Microsoft C++ unhandled exception: winrt::hresult_error in background thread

Tags: c++, windows, winrt-xaml

Simplest C++ code that prompts user credential via `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` API throws unhandled exception tied with XAML processing in background thread.

Code sample:

```
    CString me(_T("MYLOGING"));
    CString url(_T("Header"));
    CString message(_T("Enter credentials for ..."));

    CREDUI_INFOW credInfo;
    credInfo.pszCaptionText = url;
    credInfo.hbmBanner = nullptr;
    credInfo.hwndParent = m_hWnd;
    credInfo.pszMessageText = message;
    credInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CREDUI_INFOW);

    DWORD bufferSize = 1024;
    LPBYTE pBuffer = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(CoTaskMemAlloc(bufferSize));
    CredPackAuthenticationBuffer(0, me.GetBuffer(), _T(""), pBuffer, &bufferSize);
    me.ReleaseBuffer();

    ULONG authPackage = 0;
    LPVOID outCredBuffer = nullptr;
    ULONG outCredSize = 0;
    BOOL save = false;

    auto result = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(&credInfo,
        0,
        &authPackage,
        pBuffer,
        bufferSize,
        &outCredBuffer, &outCredSize, &save, CREDUIWIN_GENERIC | CREDUIWIN_ENUMERATE_CURRENT_USER | CREDUIWIN_CHECKBOX);
```

It's native C++ ATL application. Main thread is initialized as OLE thread (STA).
Exception occurs in worker thread in SHCore.dll module.
Exception stack:

```
>   KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    ucrtbase.dll!_CxxThrowException()   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::throw_hresult() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_ApplicationModel_Core_ICoreApplication<struct winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::ICoreApplication>::GetCurrentView(void) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication,winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::ICoreApplication>::call<<lambda_bfab539c4ec1a908cc512cf8f1e69054> & __ptr64>()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!DispatcherHelper::InitializeFromUIThread() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::produce<RevealBackgroundBrushFactory,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::IRevealBackgroundBrushFactory>::CreateInstance()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_IAppBarButtonFactory<struct winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IAppBarButtonFactory>::CreateInstance(struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const &,struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!Private::XamlRuntimeType::ActivateInstance()   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8084e2()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c80847c()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9377f6()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c97693b()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d1466()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c87e27a()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c829b41()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c882ed5()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c881d7c()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c882917()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c886ad5()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88564b()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884efe()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884b52()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88505c()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884b9e()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8e117f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8e0e62()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4ca97f62()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d68ea()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d6212()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8821ec()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c882917()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c886ad5()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88564b()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884efe()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884b52()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88505c()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884b9e()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8c8fc1()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c884cbd()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8e117f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8e0e62()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4ca98011()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d6793()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d5348()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d5024()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8f3979()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8c1051()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8f2b94()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8f2c8d()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8f60ab()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9d6022()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9d5f39()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88219f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c882917()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c886ad5()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88564b()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8ef340()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8f63d0()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9d6022()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9d5f39()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c88219f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c87dab6()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c834e2f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c834d65()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8348f6()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c834857()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c974b6c()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c974c14()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c975388()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c974e55()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9ef2c8()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9ef1f7()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c976f05()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c8d117e()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c880617()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c87e821()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c881d3b()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c87dab6()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c95e3f1()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c994bdd()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c963967()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c963799()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c96368f()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ffc4c9635ea()  Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    Windows.UI.Cred.dll!Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(class Platform::Object ^,class Windows::Foundation::Uri ^,enum Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::ComponentResourceLocation)    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Cred.dll!CredUX::Frame::[CredUX::__IFramePublicNonVirtuals]::InitializeComponent(void)   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Cred.dll!CredUX::Frame::Frame(class Platform::Object ^)  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Cred.dll!PlatformExceptionNoThrowBoundaryCPlusPlus<<lambda_433453e7a9ea4a090df15fe007d36c45> >() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Cred.dll!CredUXViewProviderImpl::GetView(struct IInspectable *,struct IInspectable * *)  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.CredDialogController.dll!CredUXViewDefinition::v_GetRootElement(struct IInspectable *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.CredDialogController.dll!ViewDefinitionBase::_EnsureViewInitialized(void)    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.CredDialogController.dll!ViewDefinitionBase::get_RootUIElement(struct Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElement * *) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll!XAMLHostWindowImpl::_InitializeXamlContent(void)    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll!XAMLHostWindowImpl::_CreateHostWindow(void) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll!XAMLHostWindowImpl::_Show(void) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll!DispatchableTaskWithContext<<lambda_c7ef36ba2d0f18b849cd80403bdd8ff8> >::Dispatch() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll!ASTAThreadHost::s_ASTAThreadHostStartThreadProc(void *) Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    SHCore.dll!_WrapperThreadProc() Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
```

Does anybody know how fix it?
I can ignore this exception, in this case mentioned thread will be destroyed but Credential dialog is opened and looks like works fine.

I see this exception in Win10 1809 and 1903 builds. Older Win10 1803 build doesn't contain it.

**UPDATE:**
Windows 7 doesn't contain this bug also. So looks like as if it relates only Win10 builds with system components created with C++ WinRT.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've tried to debug place of crash (disassembled method `winrt::impl::consume_Windows_ApplicationModel_Core_ICoreApplication<>()`) and looks like `HRESULT` code from `winrt::throw_hresult()` exception is **80070490h**. 
What does it mean?
Trace output at exception moment:

```
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Proj\ME\x64\Debug\ME.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc140ud.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.737_none_05b6437c071e554b\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.17763.737_none_36a1366161b0cf19\GdiPlus.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\credui.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x4b94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wincredui.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.CredDialogController.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Cred.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wincorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\InputHost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rmclient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\LanguageOverlayUtil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47mrm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47Langs.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
onecore\base\appmodel\statemanager\apiset\lib\statespace.cpp(107)\kernelbase.dll!00007FFC6F439258: (caller: 00007FFC6F43910B) ReturnHr(1) tid(5204) 80073D54 Процесс не имеет идентификатора пакета.
onecore\base\appmodel\statemanager\apiset\lib\statemanager.cpp(53)\kernelbase.dll!00007FFC6F43914B: (caller: 00007FFC4C894AB5) ReturnHr(2) tid(5204) 80073D54 Процесс не имеет идентификатора пакета.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_9172c4e962e5b3ee\nvldumdx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_9172c4e962e5b3ee\nvwgf2umx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\Tools\NvCameraWhitelisting64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1248 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ME.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\Tools\NvCameraWhitelisting64.dll'
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2210 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC6F469129 (KernelBase.dll) in ME.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x000000008000000B, 0x0000000080070490, 0x0000000000000014, 0x00000091846FB080).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC6F469129 in ME.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x00000091846FB500.
```

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm calling my code with CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials form MAIN UI tread, not from worker thread! But during the call of CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials it creates several worker threads (form module SHCore.dll) and one of them crashes with unhandled exception.

Comment: Okay, I guess what you see is that CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials() was re-implemented on Win10, now using the "native" Win10 gadgets.  This is quite painful, no way to get a try/catch injected into that code.  Do look in the Output window for any assert messages, this kind of code does get chatty when a debugger is attached.  You'd otherwise have to look for environmental stuff for a reason for this to fail.  Like a wrong CoInitializeEx() argument, no window that can be the parent of the dialog, that kind of stuff.

Comment: @HansPassant, I've added "UPDATE 2" with HRESULT code, can it help?

Comment: That's ERROR_NOT_FOUND, "Element not found".  Nope, that doesn't help much.  0x80073D54 is mildly more interesting, APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE, "The process has no package identity", but that's entirely normal in a legacy winapi program.  To be clear, does this exception actually cause your program to fail or the dialog to misbehave?  I suspect it doesn't and you are just seeing internal Microsoft code using threads and exceptions in their implementation.  That's quite normal.  Just keep motoring.

Comment: @HansPassant, Yes, application works normal and dialog is shown as expected, without problem. But this unhandled exception makes me crazy when i run app from studio under debugger. Everything in it shows that something is not correct in system libs. Currently I've marked winrt::hresult_error to ignore, but I'm worrying does not it be worse?
Thanks

Comment: It is not unhandled when your program keeps running.  Yes, annoying that the debugger stops on the first-chance exception but there isn't much you can do about it but pressing F5.  Or filter it, like you did.  You might have gotten into the habit of always using the feature since any C++ exception tends to spell trouble.  But doesn't work so well anymore on Win10, you do favor only turning on the debugger option if you actually have to diagnose an C++ exception that is caught inappropriately.  Hopefully not for a while to come.

Comment: The code is trying to detect what kind of app it is running in. The exception is caught and handled. This is normal for a non-UWP app.

Comment: @RaymondChen, a bit strange way to detect, isn't it? It's especially strange because MS [doesn't recommend us to use exception as "failed" result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/error-handling)

Comment: Yes. But `GetCurrentView` is a function from a simpler time where the only apps that used the Windows Runtime were UWP apps. Calling it from a Win32 app would make no sense, right?

Comment: @RaymondChen as it's shown in my example, i don't call either `GetCurrentView` or any other WinRT\UWP functions. `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` is single API function that I's called and it's desktop function. So, is it make sense to receive WinRT exception thrown inside desktop function? I think it's question to MS not to me.

Comment: The credential dialog appears to be written in xaml. The xaml framework is trying to see what kind of app it is running in.

Comment: @RaymondChen :) Yep, I understand it. I just surprised that "xaml framework" uses winrt exception to process unsuccessful result at this detection step instead of using returned result as MS recommends to others.

Comment: As I noted, GetCurrentView (which is not part of Xaml) was not originally designed to be used outside of UWP. If used from a Win32 app, it throws an exception. Xaml is the victim here.

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial and error phase I set

```
credInfo.hwndParent = NULL;
```

and it worked. The downside is that the dialog is not centered anymore. Until now I thought that this issue only occured whe using Qt.